# Notepad++ - Add link html to beginning/end of every line using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm not as comfortable with RegEx as I'd like to be. What I'm trying to do is prepend every line (of a list of URL's) with `<a href="` and then end each line with `"></a>`

for the prepend, I've been using Replace with regular expressions: ^ with `<a href="`

this works alright, however, there are certain blank lines that get `<a href="` added to them. Is it possible to replace the beginning of each line only if there's more than 1 character in the line?

And as for doing the end of the line, I have no idea. Any help would be much appreciated--I have a very large amount of url's in different text files to go through to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seach and replace by `^(?=.)` and `(?<=.)$` instead. The period implies "any character, excluding a linebreak". combined with `^` and `$`, it would be the start and end of a line that is followed by (or preceeded by in the case of `$`) a character.  This example combines it with positive lookahead and lookbehind to ensure that you don't replace any of the original line but append/prepend instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead (at least if you upgrade to Notepad++ 6).

```
Find what: ^(?!$)
```

And for line endings:

```
Find what: (?!^)$
```

Taking the first one as an example, it matches at the start of a line (`^`) but only if `$` does not match at that position - i.e. if it is not a line ending at the same time.

An alternative approach does both replacements in one replacement (and the assertion as well):

```
Find what: ^.+$
Replacement: <a href="$0"></a>
```

In fact, you can even omit the anchors, due to the greediness of the `+`, the pattern will always consume whole lines (but only if there is at least one character):

```
Find what: .+
Replacement: <a href="$0"></a>
```

Note that any of these will wrap your anchor around lines that contain only spaces and tabs. The best way to avoid that is to modify the third pattern:

```
Find what: ^[ \t]*\S[^\r\n]*
Replacement: <a href="$0"></a>
```

Starting at the beginning of a line we consume all spaces and tabs (no line breaks). Then we require one non-space character (`\S`). And then we consume as many non-line-break characters as possible. Due to greediness, there is again no need for the `$` anchor.